# solution to a std::vector of std::shared_ptr leaking due to circular reference

Tags: pointers, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I've gotten myself into a pickle: I'm coding a tree graph structure, where each layer contains a vector of pointers to previous layers (super types) and pointers to following (sub types) layers.

As you can imagine, this is a circular reference:

```
[last] -(super)-> [current]
[current] -(sub)-> [last]
```

When I allocate a new `layer` I make sure I move it to `current`
and when I re-assign last to current, again I move it.

However, this doesn't solve the leak, in fact the only solution I've found is using raw pointers.

Here's a minified example omitting large parts of the code:

```
struct layer
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> words;
    std::vector<layer*> sub_classes;
    std::vector<layer*> super_classes;
}
```

The actual iteration is of `wordnet senses` which populate a tree graph.
The function that does the `hypernyms` (e.g., super-types of a word) is:

```
void iterate_sense(
                        Synset * sense,
                        std::shared_ptr<layer> last,
                        graph & rhs,
                        int lexical
                      )
    {
        std::shared_ptr<layer> current;
        while (sense && last)
        {
            current = std::move(get_layer(sense));
            last->super_classes.push_back(current.get());
            current->sub_classes.push_back(last.get());
            if (sense->ptrlist)
            {
                iterate_sense(sense->nextss, 
                              last,
                              rhs, lexical);
            }
            last = std::move(current);
            sense = sense->ptrlist;
        }
    }
```

Those pointers are owned by another class `graph`.
When I use in `layer`

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<layer>> sub_classes;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<layer>> super_classes;
```

Valgrind reports lost bytes.

### 1

What is the *correct* or *elegant* way of solving this?
I assume that using raw pointers is not the best solution?

### 2

Am I correct to assume that the moment the owner `graph` is lost,
the raw pointers will become invalid?
This isn't much of a problem because `layers` themselves reside only in graphs.

### 3

I've read around SO and google that the correct usage is via combination of `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` however I don't understand how a weak_ptr would be used in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

Smart pointers, are about owner ships. It says who is responsible for a certain Object. Semantic is basically split as follows:

- `std::unique_ptr<>`: one function/object is the owner and responsible of the object.
- `std::shared_ptr<>`: several function/objects are the owner and responsible of the object.
- `raw pointer`: someone else is owner and responsible of the object.

In your case I would recommend following semantic: A Layer is the owner of its child layers. A Child is not the owner of its parent.

Following this I'd use

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<layer>> sub_classes;
std::vector<layer*> super_classes;e
```

For `iterate_sense` I'd suggest to use following signature:

```
void iterate_sense(
                    Synset * sense,
                    layer* last,
                    graph & rhs,
                    int lexical
                  )
```

This function is not fully or partially owning the object in variable `last`. It only is granted limited access to it.

## 2

Not sure in which way `graph` is owning these pointers. If `graph` is actually the owner with `std::unique_ptr<>` you can use only `raw pointers` in `layers`. This is exactly the correct way to use it.

## 3

In some cases it is possible to use std::weak_ptr<> to break circular references. I can not recommend using them for this. If you have a clean design of your data structures, it usually is very easy to say who is responsible/owner of a object. There are not that many cases where it is not clear. In these unclear cases, where more then an object is management/owned by several other objects you need std::shared_ptr<>. Under these circumstances you might need access to an object of which you don't know if it still exist. In this case you might want to use std::weak_ptr<>.

Comment: a `graph` owns all layers. Then each `layer` points to `super_classes` and `sub_classes`. The same pointers are used for both classes. The problem is that layers *might* have `super_classes` and not `sub_classes` (case of a hypernym) or *might* have `sub_classes` but not `super_classes` (case of a hyponym). Thus, is it really a good approach for struct `layer` to own the pointers? I will however try your suggestion, and see how it works out.

Comment: If `graph` owns all layers, it should have `std::unique_ptr<>` pointing to the layers and the layers them self only using `raw pointers`. Specially if you know that the layers are only valid as long as `graph` exists. This seems to be even a better approach.